# Fast Loopback Socket Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, winsock2

I currently searching for some performance problems in our distributed multiprocess application!

Thats the reason I would like to try fast loopback sockets
SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH [descreption](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx) and [msdn desc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj841212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

here is my code fragment for opening server socket:

```
TcpipSocket::TcpipSocket(FullIPAddress const& address)
: m_Port(address.m_Port)
, m_IPAddress(address.m_Address)
, m_Socket(INVALID_SOCKET)
{
if (0 == ms_NumberOfInstances)
{
    initNetwork(NULL);  // here i call the WSAStartup function
}

m_Socket = ::socket(TCPSocketFamily, TCPSocketType, TCPProtocol);
if (INVALID_SOCKET == m_Socket)
{
    throwException(ConstrName);
}
else
{
    // this is the code to enable the FAST Loopback Sockets see [1]
    int OptionValue =1;
    DWORD NumberOfBytesReturned =0;
    int status=::WSAIoctl(m_Socket,
        SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH,
        &OptionValue,
        sizeof(OptionValue),
        NULL,
        0,
        &NumberOfBytesReturned,
        0,
        0);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == status) 
    {
        DWORD LastError = ::WSAGetLastError();

        if (WSAEOPNOTSUPP == LastError) 
        {
            std::ostringstream out;
            out << "This system is not Windows Windows Server 2012/Windows 8, \n";
            out << "and the call is not supported.\n";
            out << "ErrorNumber: "<< LastError;

            throwException(out.str().c_str());
        }
        else 
        {
            std::ostringstream out;
            out << "TcpipSocket::Loopback Fastpath WSAIoctl failed: ";
            out << "\nErrorNumber: "<< LastError;

            throwException(out.str().c_str());

        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem: I always receive the error **WSAEOPNOTSUPP**
running the example on Windows 8 64 bit with all updates..

What did I miss? regarding the example, it should work straight forward?

The code is written on a win 7 x64 with VS2012 
I using the Platform toolset "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)"

Comment: This article have some help http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I read the article, was no help for me.

Comment: @nobs What's your Windows's full version number?

Comment: don't know any more
used it on a testsystem, but its already 3 years ago 
stopped the expirement because I was never able to get it workig